# retrieving string from LPVOID

Tags: c++, string

Can someone explain and help me out here please.
Lets say i have function like this where lpData holds a pointer to the data i want.

```
void foo(LPVOID lpData) {

}
```

What is the proper way to retreive this. This works but i get weird characters at the end

```
void foo(LPVOID lpData) {
    LPVOID *lpDataP = (LPVOID *)lpData;
char *charData = (char*)lpDataP;
    //i log charData....
}
```

I would prefer to use strings but I don't understand how to retrieve the data, i just get null pointer error when i try to use string. lpData holds a pointer right? (But my function is lpData not *lpData) so it isn't working? Am i doing this all wrong?

```
string *datastring = reinterpret_cast<std::string *>(lpData);
```

is what im trying.

Comment: `LPVOID` is already a `void *`. If you pass a pointer to a `std::string`, just use `static_cast<std::string *>`.

Comment: Why are you casting from `LPVOID` (`void *`, a pointer to anything) to `LPVOID *` (`void **`, a pointer to a pointer to anything)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works but i get weird characters at the end

That means that your string isn't null-terminated—that is, it doesn't have a `NUL` byte (`0`) marking the end of the string.

C strings have to be [null-terminated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).* When you log a C string (`char *`), it keeps logging characters until it finds a `NUL`. If there wasn't one on the end of the string, it'll keep going through random memory until it finds one (or until you hit a page fault and crash). This is bad. And there's no way to fix it; once you lose the length, there's no way to get it back.

However, an unterminated string *along with its length* can be useful. Many functions can take the length alongside the `char *`, as an extra argument (e.g., the `string` constructor) or otherwise (e.g., width specifiers in `printf` format strings).

So, if you take the length, and only call functions that also take the length—or just make a null-terminated copy and use that—you're fine. So:

```
void foo(LPVOID lpData, int cchData) {
    string sData(static_cast<const char *>(lpData), cchData);
    // now do stuff with sData
}
```

Meanwhile, casting from `LPVOID` (aka `void *`, aka pointer-to-anything) to `LPVOID *` (aka `void **`, aka pointer to pointer-to-anything) to then cast to `char *` (pointer-to-characters) is wrong (and should be giving you a compiler warning in the second cast; if you're getting warnings and ignoring them, don't do that!). Also, it's generally better to use modern casts instead of C-style casts, and it's always better to be const-correct when there's no down side; it just makes things more explicit to the reader and safer in the face of future maintenance.

Finally:

```
string *datastring = reinterpret_cast<std::string *>(lpData);
```

This is almost certainly wrong.** The `LPVOID` is just pointing at a bunch of characters. You're saying you want to interpret those characters as if they were a `string` object. But a `string` object is some header information (maybe a length and capacity, etc.) plus a pointer to a bunch of characters. Treating one as the other is going to lead to garbage or crashes.***

---

* Yes, you're using C++, not C, but a `char *` is a "C string".

** If you actually have a `string` object that you've kept alive somewhere, and you stashed a pointer to that object in an `LPVOID` and have now retrieved it (e.g., with `SetWindowLongPtr`/`GetWindowLongPtr`), then a cast from `LPVOID` to `string *` would make sense. But I doubt that's what you're doing. (If you are, then you don't need the `reinterpret_cast`. The whole point of `void *` is that it's not interpreted, so there's nothing to reinterpret from. Just use `static_cast`.)

*** Or, worst of all, it may appear to work, but then lead to hard-to-follow crashes or corruption. Some standard C++ libraries use a special allocator to put the header right before the characters and return a pointer to the first character, so that a `string` can be used anywhere a `char *` can. Inside the `string` class, every method has to fudge the `this` pointer backward; for example, instead of just saying `m_length` it has to do something like `static_cast<_string_header *>(this)[-1]->m_length`. But the other way around doesn't work—if you just have a bunch of characters, not a `string` object, that fudge is going to read whatever bytes happened to be allocated right before the characters and try to interpret them as an integer, so you may end up thinking you have a string of length 0, or 182423742341241243.

Comment: Thanks you explained that very well, bad mistakes on my part.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways:

```
void foo(LPVOID lpData)
{
    char *charData = (char*)lpData;
    //i log charData....
}
```

or

```
void foo(LPVOID lpData)
{
    char *charData = static_cast<char*>lpData;
    //i log charData....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a **std::string** from an **LPVOID** in C++, you'll need to perform the necessary type casting and memory interpretation. However, this assumes that the LPVOID indeed contains a **std::string** object or a C-style null-terminated string. If you're dealing with a **std::string**, you should proceed differently, as **std::string** manages its own memory, and direct casting is not advisable.

Here's how you can retrieve a **std::string** from an **LPVOID**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    LPVOID lpVoidPointer = /* your LPVOID pointer */;

    if (lpVoidPointer) {
        // Assuming the LPVOID contains a null-terminated C-style string
        char* charPointer = static_cast<char*>(lpVoidPointer);
        
        std::string str(charPointer);
        
        std::cout << "Retrieved string: " << str << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Invalid LPVOID pointer." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code assumes that the **LPVOID** contains a null-terminated C-style string and uses it to construct a **std::string**. If the **LPVOID** contains a **std::string** object directly, casting it as shown above is not appropriate, and you should consider other methods for serializing and deserializing data.

Remember to ensure that the **LPVOID** pointer is valid and points to the expected data to avoid undefined behavior or crashes.